# Patching SharePoint 2013 April 2014 CU directly to July 2015 CU

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

We have SharePoint 2013 Production farm which is SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 with May 2014 CU ([KB2878240](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2878240)) and build version is 15.0.4605.1002. We referred to [Todd Klindt blog](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) and need to know if we can directly skip SharePoint 2014 CUs and patch the latest July 2015 on the SharePoint farm.

We found that in Aug 2014 CU and Sept 2014 CUs were **NOT cumulative**. Its also confirmed by   Stefan Goßner for Aug 2014 CU and Spet 2014 CU.

**Q:** Is there any dependency if we move directly SharePoint April 2014 CU to July 2015 CU?

**Q:** In May 2015, SharePoint released security patch KB2952166. Will July 2015 CU include all the security patch July 2015?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To wrap this up with the same answer on TN, yes you can move directly to the July 2015 CU which will include the security hotfixes, as well. CUs as of, I believe May 2015, always include security hotfixes for the month they're released in (and of course being CUs, include previous months). The only dependency to move the May 2015 or higher CUs is that you have Service Pack 1 installed, which you indicate that you do.